# Networking wireless and wired connection simultaneously

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I am on Windows 7 and wan to use my wireless connection for all the internet traffic and my Ethernet (wired) connection i.e. my LAN for connection to local office network.

I have Kept Wireless as
192.168.1.111
255.255.255.0
192.168.1.1

and wired as
192.168.1.16
255.255.0.0
no gateway

But after this it treats my wired connection as unidentified network?

How to recognize my wired connection as office LAN?

Answer (score 1):

Do your wireless and wired connections actually connect to the same LAN?  If they do then first up, why do you want to do this?  It seems a bit odd.
I'm not sure why your LAN connection subnet mask is different to your wireless, but I doubt that it is correct.
To achieve what you want, you can either setup your wired connection to have no default gateway.  Windows will prefer the wired connection, but by having no gateway will be forced to use the wireless for internet access.  (actually for any non-local traffic at all).
Your other option is to leave both connections settings alone (presumably DHCP issues them) and then change your local routing table to delete the default route from your wired adapter. (run an elevated command prompt and look at the ROUTE command).  If you are happy to add the result of ROUTE PRINT to your question then I should be able to tell you the exact command to run to delete the correct default route.
As for why Win 7 shows a un-identified network, I'm not totally sure.  I did have similar issues at home with a PC that I had issed a static IP address to.  win 7 appears to use information like DNS domain and DHCP server to tell which network it is attached to.  By setting a static address with no DNS domain it doesn't have any information to use to recognise the network.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on Windows so maybe I don't understand the problem, but I believe you should be looking at routing tables for this kind of setup, available via the command `route` in the command-line prompt.